# transferring object ownership on std::allocator rebind

Tags: c++, standard-library, allocator

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where I am implementing a replacement for the standard allocator used in containers like `std::vector`. But, I've run in to an issue. My implementation relies on the allocator owning a handle to a resource. In the case where the `rebind` feature is used, I would need to transfer ownership of the handle to the new allocator. Something like this:

```
template< class T >
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    template< class U >
    explicit MyAllocator( const MyAllocator< U >& other ) throw() 
        :  h_( other.Detach() ) // can't do this to a `const`
    {
    };

    // ...

private:
    HANDLE Detach()
    {
        HANDLE h = h_;
        h_ = NULL;
        return h;
    };

    HANDLE h_;
}; // class MyAllocator
```

Unfortunately, I can't relieve the old allocator of the handle ownership because it is `const`. If I remove `const` from the rebind constructor, then the containers won't accept it.

```
error C2558: class 'MyAllocator<T>' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'
```

Is there a good way around this issue?

Comment: Aren't allocators required to not to have state?? There's a classic article on allocators somewhere, by Matt Austern, IIRC, but I can't find it now...

Comment: Here's the article: [http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403759](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403759). And from a quick glance at [this discussion](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2004-10/msg00303.html), it seems that stateful allocators are indeed supported, although std lib implementations supporting used to be an issue.

Comment: @sbi - Thank you for the article and discussion. I was going to have a followup question about how to handle `std::swap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you declare `h_` as `mutable`?

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing much about allocators (never needed them): Your copy ctor takes a `const` ref, thus promising to not to change the `other` object, but you attempt to change it anyway. Although there's cases where classes were designed that way (`std::auto_ptr`), this does seem fishy.
Syntactically, you could always declare `h_` `mutable`, and make `Detach()` a `const` member function, but I'd seriously question the *semantics* of this setup, before hacking my way through the syntactic jungle using a broadsword.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with an extra level of indirection but it's not an ideal solution. Basically, your allocator would have a *pointer* to a handle which would be allocated/deallocated in the constructor/destructor. The handle that it points to would be non-const throughout, so you can "move" the handle from one allocator to another. This does add some overhead to the allocator though.

I don't know your exact case but it seems that  a stateful allocator that's non-trivially copyable should be carefully considered for all its implications. Is there an alternate way you can simplify its design so it doesn't have a move-only handle?

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer the ownership, because the allocator may be copied and rebound multiple times even in a single container and the resulting instances used simultaneously.

You'll have to share the resource instead. Create an indirection for the resource with reference-count. Something like:

```
class SharedHandle {
    HANDLE h_;
    int count;
    SharedHandle(HANDLE h) : h_(h), count(1) {}
    ~SharedHandle() { CloseHandle(h_); } // or whatever to release the resource.
    SharedHandle *Ref() { ++count; return this; }
    void Unref() { if(!--count) delete this; }
}
```

and than:

```
explicit MyAllocator( const MyAllocator< U >& other ) throw() 
:  h_( other.h_->Ref() )
```

In addition to containers that naturally need to allocate heterogenous blocks like `hash_map`/`unordered_map`, Microsoft implementation of containers is known to allocate various strange things. When I traced allocations in one Windows application, there were many allocations of strange sizes comming from somewhere inside STL.